Reference Request: In Zariski &Samuel's Commutative Algebra (volume I), should the definition of length of an ideal be modified?
This is more a reference request question than a technique one.
I hope someone who has read Zariski, Samuel's Commutative Algebra (volume I) could answer it. (It seems few people use it nowadays).
In Zariski, Samuel's Commutative Algebra (volume I), the definition of the length of an ideal is as follows
(the book uses $A-B$ to mean the quotient module $A/B$, and the length of a module $M$ means the length of its composition series: $M=M_0\supsetneqq M_1\supsetneqq \cdots\supsetneqq M_r=(0)$ has length $r$).

But while reading, I found that if we define the length of an ideal as the length of $R_M/\mathfrak a^e$ as a module over itself,
instead of the length of $R_M/\mathfrak a^e$ as an $R-$module, then the theorems on the book following the definition seems more reasonable.
An example is this question I asked before (Theorem 24). Confusion on the proof of Zariski and Samuel's Commutative Algebra, Theorem 24 in Chapter 4
Also, in theorem 26 below,
$$ \mathfrak{q}_1^e/\mathfrak q^e\supsetneqq \mathfrak{q}_2^e/\mathfrak q^e\supsetneqq\cdots\supsetneqq  \mathfrak{q}_r^e/\mathfrak q^e=(0) $$
is a chain of $R_M/\mathfrak q^e$-module. The author claimed its maximal possible length is the (ideal-)length of $\mathfrak{q}$,
which may be incorrect if we define length as author did, i.e. define  the (ideal-)length of $\mathfrak{q}$ as the length of the $R-$module $R_M/\mathfrak q^e$.
Define the (ideal-)length of $\mathfrak{q}$ as the length of the $R/\mathfrak q^e-$module $R_M/\mathfrak q^e$ seems to make more sense.

So, this is more a reference-requset    question than a maths technique one.
I want to know if someone knows an errta (written by Zariski and Samuel themselves, or written by others but considered reliable) talking about this issue.
If you have read this part of the book, it will also be kind of you to leave your thought on this issue.
I also would like to know if this definition (or similar ones) appears on other books.
I looked up some commutative algebra book and did not find similar definition.

Good catch! It's subtly false and we're dealing with a very consistent typo, but everything works as intended if the ideal length is defined as the length of $R_M/\mathfrak a^e$ over itself or, equivalently, over $R_M$, as the OP suggests.
A little historical context: The definition of the length of a $\mathfrak p$-primary ideal $\mathfrak q$ goes back to Krull's book Idealtheorie (1935), even though the concept was there already in Krull's Primidealketten in allgemeinen Ringberichen (1928). The definition boils down to the length of the Artinian ring $R_\mathfrak p/\mathfrak q R_\mathfrak p$. And (crucially) not the length of $R_\mathfrak p/\mathfrak q R_\mathfrak p$ as an $R$-module.
I am not aware of a critical analysis of Zariski--Samuel's generalisation in the literature. Beachy and Weekly, Piecewise noetherian rings (1984), refer to the definition of Samuel and Zariski, but use the "correct" definition.
It remains to show that there really is a difference, which was actually not obvious to me at first (and I clearly missed this when I first read the chapter a few years ago).
Consider the introductory paragraph before the definition in Zariski--Samuel: "A more reasonable definition would be to define the length of the ideal $\mathfrak a$ as being the length $\mathop{l}(R-\mathfrak a)$ of the difference-module $R-\mathfrak a$; however this length would still be infinite [...] for example whenever $\mathfrak a$ is a prime ideal which is not maximal." Then the authors proceed to define $\lambda(\mathfrak a)=\mathop{l}(R_M-\mathfrak a^e)$ where $M$ is as in the OP. However, the objective that the ideal length should have a chance of being finite even if $R/\mathfrak a$ is not of finite length is clearly not met if the length of $R_M-\mathfrak a^e$ is taken as an $R$-module instead of an $R_M$-module: Since $M$ is prime for $\mathfrak a$ (i.e., contains only elements acting as non-zero divisors on $R/\mathfrak a$), $R/\mathfrak a\hookrightarrow (R/\mathfrak a)_M=R_M/\mathfrak a^e$ is injective, thus establishing $R/\mathfrak a$ as an $R$-sub-module of $ (R/\mathfrak a)_M$ and so $\mathop{l}_R(R_M/\mathfrak a^e)=\mathop{l}_R(R/\mathfrak a)+\mathop{l}_R((R/\mathfrak a)_M/(R/\mathfrak a))\ge\mathop{l}_R(R/\mathfrak a)$. This is clearly not what the authors intended. Moreover, the problem indeed disappears (and the definition specialises to Krull's terminology) if we take the length of $R_M-\mathfrak a^e$ as an $R_M$-module instead. In fact, this is the whole reason why we're localising in the first place.
I have re-checked the proofs of this chapter and this issue seems to be consistent. For example, notice the footnote on p. 234: "Observe that the set of submodules of the $R$-module $R_M-\mathfrak a^e$ coincides with the set of ideals of the ring $R_M/\mathfrak a^e$, since $\mathfrak a^e$ annihilates $R_M-\mathfrak a^e$." — the indicated argument only works if we're considering $R_M-\mathfrak a^e$ as an $R_M$-module, not as an $R$-module. As a result, Theorem 24 is just plain wrong with the verbatim definition, but, of course, holds with the corrected one.

Thank you! This answer is exactly what I am looking for.

By the way, do you know whether Idealtheorie (1935) or Primidealketten in allgemeinen Ringberichen (1928) has an English copy?

Dear, @Asigan, I'm glad that this was helpful. Thank you for spotting this, it was very interesting to think about. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any translations, but being German, this could very easily be ignorance on my part.

Well. Thanks again for your answer! I have found a copy of the 2nd edition of the book in German now. Could you please point out which section and paragraph Krull mentioned the concept of the length of a primary ideal in the book Idealtheorie? I think I can try if GPT can help me translate that into English.

§ 2 13. contains the initial definition: "Ist $\mathfrak O$ ein [primärer] O-Ring, so möge unter der „Länge” des Ideals $\mathfrak a$ die Länge der Restklassengruppe $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak a$ [...] verstanden werden." — meaning: "If $\mathfrak O$ is a zero-dimensional noetherian ring, the length of an ideal $\mathfrak a\subset \mathfrak O$ shall be the length of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak a$." ...

But the fun stuff is in §2 14 (p. 34 in my edition). I'm translating very loosely: If $\mathfrak q$ is $\mathfrak p$-primary in the integral domain $\mathfrak J$, then we may form the localisation $\mathfrak J_\mathfrak p$ and the quotient ring $\overline{\mathfrak{O}}=\mathfrak{J}{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak q\cdot \mathfrak J{\mathfrak p}$. [...] The length of this ring shall be called the length of $\mathfrak q$.

Thanks! I feel sorry to disturb you again. But in 2.13 the "Ist $\mathfrak D$ ein [primärer] O-Ring..." paragraph again says "Sinne von 11." and referenced to 11. Which paragraph of 11 mentioned the way to define Lange of $\mathfrak D/\mathfrak a$?

Krull introduces "Operatorgruppen" (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_with_operators) and notes (§ 1, 1., p. 2) that "all theorems about general Groups with operators can immediately be applied to the ideal theory" where the operators are just the ring acting on itself by multiplication. Essentially, an $R$-module is an abelian group with operators $R$. For such a Group of operators, the length is defined on p. 28: "Ist $\mathfrak B_1$ eine Untergruppe von $\mathfrak A$, $\dots$". Applied to rings/modules, this really results in the modern standard definition.

Thanks for informing me that! I think I can catch it now. By the way, Krull has referred to van der Waerden's article a few times. Therefore I deduced that the same concept may also appeared on van der Waerden's book, and fortunately found one. I will also post an answer on this since it may be more accessible to those who can not read German. Thanks again for your help sincerely.

Ben has wrote an answer and said Krull came up with the concept.
Since Krull quoted van der Waerden's article a few times in his book,
I thought maybe conversely, van der Waerden's later written Algebra will also mention this concept.
Luckily I did find it.
In the fifth edition of van der Waerden's Algebra, volume II, section 15.11, THE LENGTH OF A PRIMARY IDEAL.
CHAINS OF PRIMARY IDEALS IN NOETHERIAN RINGS, the highlighted paragraph was what Zariski & Samuel intended to establish. (van der Waerden established it for primary ideals, and Zariski& Samuel generalized it to ideals with a primary decomposition.)
I give some explanations after the picture.


Note that for convenience, van der Waerden redenoted $\mathfrak o'\gets \mathfrak o$, $\mathfrak p'\gets \mathfrak p$ in the highlighted paragraph.
But in the following we let $\mathfrak o, \mathfrak p$ denote the original ring and ideal,
and $\mathfrak o', \mathfrak p'$ be the new ring and ideal obtained from localization, to avoid ambiguity.
In the chain
\begin{equation*}
\mathfrak o'\supset \mathfrak q_1\supset\cdots\supset \mathfrak q_l=(0),
\end{equation*}
each $\mathfrak q_i$ is a $\mathfrak o'=S^{-1}\mathfrak o (\overset{\mathfrak q=(0)}{=}S^{-1}\mathfrak o /\mathfrak q^e)$-module,
but the class of sub $\mathfrak o$-submodule of $\mathfrak o'$ may be larger than sub $\mathfrak o$'-modules.
This also suggests that Zariski & Samuel's definition should be modified.
Remark: van der Waerden said the $\mathfrak q_i$s should be $\mathfrak p^e$-primary.
But in fact, as is said in the previous paragraph, we may assume $\mathfrak q=(0)$, $\mathfrak q^e=(0)$, and then
any ideal $I\ne \mathfrak o'$  is forced to be $\mathfrak p^e-$primary.
To clarify, we have the following property:

Let $\mathfrak o$ be a ring (commutative with $1$ of course), s.t. $\mathfrak q=(0)$ is $\mathfrak p=\sqrt{(0)}$-primary.
(As a consequence any prime ideal must contain $\mathfrak p$, since $\sqrt{(0)}$ is the intersection of all prime ideals.)
Then in the localizaton ring $\mathfrak o'\equiv \mathfrak o_{\mathfrak p}$, any ideal $I\ne \mathfrak o_{\mathfrak p}$ is $\mathfrak p^e-$primary.

Proof: First we note that $\mathfrak o'$ is a local ring with $ \mathfrak p^e$ the unique maximal ideal. Then $(0)\subset I\subset \mathfrak p^e $.
Then we claim $\sqrt{(0)}=\mathfrak p^e$. There are two ways to see this:
(1) As we have noticed, prime ideals of $\mathfrak o$ must contain $\mathfrak p$, i.e. no prime ideal other than $\mathfrak p$ itself is contained in $\mathfrak p$.
Since prime ideals of $\mathfrak o'$ different from $\mathfrak o'$ and prime ideals of $\mathfrak o$ contained in $\mathfrak p$ have a bijective correspondence, therefore $\mathfrak p^e$ is the only prime ideal in $\mathfrak o'$ different from $\mathfrak o'$.
This forces $\sqrt{(0)}$, a prime ideal, to be $\mathfrak p^e$.
(2) Alternatively we check it directly. Select $x\in\mathfrak p^e$. Then $x=\frac as$ for some $a\in\mathfrak p$, $s\notin\mathfrak p$.
$\mathfrak p=\sqrt{(0)}\implies a^n=0$ for some $n$. Then $(\frac as)^n=0$, i.e. $\mathfrak p^e\subset\sqrt{(0)}$.
The converse inclusion is clear since $\mathfrak p^e$ is maximal.
Thus by taking radicals in
\begin{equation*}
(0)\subset I\subset \mathfrak p^e ,
\end{equation*}
we have $\sqrt{I}=\mathfrak p^e$.
It remains to prove $I$ is primary. If $xy\in I$ with $y\notin\sqrt{I}=\mathfrak p^e$,
then $y$ must be a unit since $\mathfrak o'$ is a local ring with $ \mathfrak p^e$ the unique maximal ideal.
Therefore $x=y^{-1}(xy)\in I$. This implies $I$ is primary. $\square$
